# Disable Three Tap Paste Gesture

Tags: settings, touchpad, mouse

i've installed libinput-gestures to get OS X-like gesture for switching workspaces.
Sometimes some previously copied text gets pasted randomly in the current workspace, after the three finger swipe up or down gesture. That's extremely annoying.

I searched a lot but didn't find any solution. 
I own a Dell XPS 13 9343. How can i disable the three tap paste gesture?

Comment: Actually, the only working solution I found is here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24330/how-can-i-turn-off-middle-mouse-button-paste-functionality-in-all-programs

Answer (score 1):

A relevant issue on a similar topic, the middle mouse button:
https://github.com/elementary/default-settings/issues/5

You might want to start a discussion on whether this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Gnome, install `gnome tweaks`, go to `keyboard and mouse` section and disable `Middle click paste`

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me, even after setting **middle click paste** to *off*, the three-finger-click still pastes, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Run `synclient -l | grep TapButton3` in terminal. You will see that `TapButton3              = 2`. We want to disable this. Run `synclient TapButton3=0` and it should work. It is only temporary for that session though.

---

A permanent solution is a bit messy.

1. We need to make sure that gnome settings daemon is not messing with our settings. To do that go to org>gnome>settings-daemon>plugins>mouse and dismiss the active option.
2. Make a directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` (if it is already not there).
3. Copy `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf` to  `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.
4. Add `Option "TapButton3" "0"` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf` in `Section "InputClass"` and `Identifier "touchpad catchall"`.
5. To enable natural scroll, you will have to add `Option "VertScrollDelta" "-77"` and `Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-77"` as well. -77 is just a negative integer with appropriate scroll speed which may differ for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just quick addition, after executing `synclient TapButton3=0` and disabling 'Middle Click Paste' I also had to restart all my applications to make them stop pasting on three-finger tap.